# Read the lines & create lists based on matching values from specific start position to till specific end

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

I have created a below text file

```
AB12345 werwer ssd fghfh
BA12345 wewewe wer sdfsf
CD44444 werwe werwe dgdg
DC44444 dsgdgfd dfgg fdgdfg
```

I want to read the lines & create lists based on matching values at position start from 2 to 6 i.e 12345 which is present in two rows. So it will create list a below

```
**List 1**                   **List 2**
AB12345 werwer ssd fghfh     CD44444 werwe werwe dgdg
BA12345 wewewe wer sdfsf     DC44444 dsgdgfd dfgg fdgdfg
```

Please let me know how to achieve this using linq.

Comment: are these values will remain static?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just group lines by substring from 2 to 6:

```
var lists = from l in File.ReadLines("fileName")
            group l by l.Substring(2,4) into g
            select g.ToList();
```

Lambda syntax:

```
var lists = File.ReadLines("fileName")
                .GroupBy(l => l.Substring(2,4))
                .Select(g => g.ToList());
```

Output:

```
[
  [ "AB12345 werwer ssd fghfh", "BA12345 wewewe wer sdfsf" ],
  [ "CD44444 werwe werwe dgdg", "DC44444 dsgdgfd dfgg fdgdfg" ]
]
```

Note you can select group directly, without converting it to list. In that case you will have also information about grouping key of each group, i.e. "1234" and "4444" in your case. E.g.

```
var groups = File.ReadLines("fileName").GroupBy(l => l.Substring(2,4));
```

Or even you can use lookup:

```
var lookup = File.ReadLines("fileName").ToLookup(l => l.Substring(2,4));
```

That will allow you easily access list of lines by their key:

```
IEnumerable<string> list1 = lookup["1234"];
IEnumerable<string> list2 = lookup["4444"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a projection using `Select` to retrieve the desired part of the line thanks to a `string.SubString` (i.e. 12345 or 44444) then apply a `GroupBy` on that value to split the input list.

Basically something like (not actually tested):

```
var results = inputList
    .Select(z => new
    {
        Match = z.Substring(2, 5),
        Value = z
    })
    .GroupBy(z => z.Match);
```